# How do I write to the console from inside start-job with BeginInvoke in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell and I'm trying to write a script to run some parallel jobs.  I'd like those jobs to output some data when they're done running, but I can't seem to get it right.  I've messed with it a bit and it sounds like Write-Output is the way to go but when I look at the objects returned by the job there isn't anything in the output array.   This is what I have so far:

```
$connection = @{ connection = (Connect-Site -Url "site.com" -Browser) }

$importScript = {

        param($p1)

        #get the list name from the file name
        $name = $_.Name.LastIndexOf(".")
        $path = $_.FullName
        $listName = $_.Name.Substring(0, $name)

    $dstSite = Connect-Site -Url "site.com" -UseCredentialsFrom $p1.connection

        Write-Output "$name, $path, $listName"

        Write-Output $dstSite
}

Write-Host "Migration started at $(Get-Date)" 

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProjExports" | 
Foreach-Object {

    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })


        if ($running.Count -le 10) {
            Start-Job {

                # create and start the job
                $p = [PowerShell]::Create()
                $null = $p.AddScript($importScript).AddArgument($connection)
                $job = $p.BeginInvoke()

                $done = $job.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()

                $out = $p.EndInvoke($job)

            }
        } else {
             $running | Wait-Job
        }
        Get-Job | Receive-Job

}
```

I'm under the impression that $out should contain the items from Write-Output of the script in AddScript but it always seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're combining runspaces and jobs, and it's not necessary.  A job can be as simple as this.  A job creates a new process, so there's somewhat of a delay.

```
'hi','you','me' | foreach-object { 
  start-job { param ($a) write-output "$a there" } -args $_ 
} | receive-job -wait -autoremovejob

you there
me there
hi there
```

If you have powershell 7, you can use start-threadjob or foreach-object -parallel instead.  Or download the [Threadjobs](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob) module in powershell 5.

Here's a real world threadjob example:

```
echo microsoft.com yahoo.com | foreach { 
  start-threadjob { 
    param ($hostname) 
    test-connection -count 1 $hostname } -argumentlist $_ 
} | receive-job -wait -autoremovejob
```

Comment: I've edited my code to reflect the missing first line.  The reason I'm doing it the way I'm doing it is because I'm trying to pass an object into each of the asynch jobs.  Using start-job -args doesn't seem to pass the full object in, but a deserialized version, which doesn't work, same with for-each -parallel.

Comment: start-threadjob and foreach-object -parallel use full objects.